# Create GridView with Grouping manually in Metro Style App

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

Ho is it possible to define the grouing in XAML without using Templates?

I like to define my GridViewItems inside the GridView like:

```
   <GridView>
     <GroupItem>
      <GridViewItem/>
      <GridViewItem/>
     <GridViewItem/>
    </GroupItem>
   <GridView>
```

But that seems to be not possible.
My GridViewItems are not sized all  the same, so I like to get a flowing layout instead of manually putting everything in StackPanels :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, I wish. I've wanted since I first saw grouping.

You have to use a `CollectionViewSource` w/code behind. Sorry about that.

Great minds, though. ;)

Best of luck!